# Are there any real-world E-voting systems in use with the Paillier cryptosystem?

Tags: reference-request, paillier, voting

There are a lot of theories of Paillier cryptosystem with references to e-voting. Are there any real-world E-voting systems in use with the Paillier cryptosystem?